# Flutter share image - open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory), null, null)

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile

https://pub.dev/packages/share

```
Dependency: 
   share: ^0.6.5+2
```

Local file directory

```
Future<String> get _localPath async {
    final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    return directory.path;
}
```

Share function

```
Future<void> _onShare(BuildContext context) async {
final RenderBox box = context.findRenderObject();
final path = await _localPath;

await Share.shareFiles(
    ['$path/assets/images/${widget.imgUrl}.png'],
    text: text,
    sharePositionOrigin: box.localToGlobal(Offset.zero) & box.size);
}
```

Button - on press

```
FlatButton(child: Text('Share'), onPressed: () => _onShare(context)),
```

I'm using this package to share image from application. I have no issue sharing text but when I add the function to share image, I keep getting errors for missing image.
Am I doing it correctly?

Comment: I think you have to save image in local before sharing.
here you are just giving image with empty data.

Comment: I'm having problem referencing image from app.

Comment: Note to anyone who encounters `PlatformException open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory), null, null)` with similar code: I found this occurs if the share plugin fails to copy the file into an external directory for sharing. That might be why it was failing when this code was using getApplicationDocumentsDirectory but it will work ok with getExternalStorageDirectory. My emulator is having problems with this, but works fine on a real device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Managed to figure out the problem.
Seems like I need to save image before I can reference the image.

```
final ByteData bytes = await rootBundle
    .load('assets/images/${widget.imgUrl}.png');
final Uint8List list = bytes.buffer.asUint8List();
final directory = (await getExternalStorageDirectory()).path;
File imgFile = File('$directory/screenshot.png');
imgFile.writeAsBytesSync(list);

Share.shareFiles(['$directory/screenshot.png'],
    sharePositionOrigin: box.localToGlobal(Offset.zero) & box.size);
```